# Removing an unnecessary legend from a visualisation in VegaLite

Tags: graph, charts, visualization, legend, vega-lite

I've created this visualization in VegaLite but I'm having an issue with the legends of my graphs. The visualization is a scatterplot, bar chart, and 2 strip plots, of which the scatterplot and bar chart have their own unique legend.

The graphs are joined together(i.e. concat)and by default in VegaLite the legends are automatically combined into one. I've separated both legends using the `resolve` channel as follows `"resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}` but when I implement this operator it creates a copy of the scatterplot's legend that is nothing more than a text legend and not interactive like the original.

I've tried tweaking the `resolve` channel as well as the `color` channel of the scatterplot in order to fix this but nothing seems to be working. How can I go about removing this text legend?

**CODE**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2018/2018-10-16/recent-grads.csv"
  },

  "title": "2018 Graduation Explorer",
  "config": {
    "title": {
      "fontSize": 20, 
      "fontWeight": "bold", 
      "offset": 15, 
      "anchor": "middle"
    },
    "axis": {
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": "bold",
      "labelFontSize": 10
    },
    "view": {
      "stroke": "#e8e8e8"
    }
  },

  "spacing": 8,
  "bounds": "full",
  "vconcat": [{
  "hconcat": [

  {  
  "height": 450,
  "width": 500,
  "mark": "circle",
  
  "params": [{
    "name": "Legend_Select",
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Major_category"]},
    "bind": "legend"
  },
  {"name": "brush", "select": {"type": "interval"}}
  ],

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}
  ],
  
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Median",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.2},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,120000]},
      "title": "Median Salary ($)" 
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Unemployment_rate",
      "type": "quantitative",  
      "axis": {"format": ".0%", "gridOpacity": 0.2},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,0.18]},
      "title": "Unemployment Rate (%)"
    },  
    "color": {   
      "condition":{
        "legend": {
          "orient": "left",
          "symbolSize": 60, 
          "titleFontSize": 10, 
          "labelFontSize": 8, 
          "title": "Major Category",
          "titleAnchor": "middle"
        },  
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
        }
      },
      "value": "lightgrey"      
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major_category", "type": "nominal", "title": "Major Category"},
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Median", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Salary"},
      {"field": "Unemployment_rate", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Unemployment Rate"}  
    ]
  }
  },
  
  {
    
  "width": 300,
  "height": 450,
  "mark": "bar",
  
  "params": [{
    "name": "Gender_Select",
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Gender"]},
    "bind": "legend"
  }],

  
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Men", "Women"], "as": ["Gender", "Total"]},
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}, 
    {"filter": {"param": "brush"}},
    {"filter": {"param": "Gender_Select"}} 
    
  ],  
  
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Major_category", 
      "type": "nominal", 
      "title": null,
      "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "Total", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Total", 
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5},
      "title": "Total No. of Graduates"
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": {
        "symbolSize": 60, 
        "titleFontSize": 10, 
        "labelFontSize": 8, 
        "title": "Gender",
        "titleAnchor": "middle"
      },  
      "field": "Gender", 
      "type": "nominal", 
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["Men", "Women"],
        "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e"]
      }
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major"},
      {"field": "Men", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Men"},
      {"field": "Women", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Women"}
    ]
  }        
  }
  
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}
  },
  
  {
  "mark": {
    "type": "tick",
    "opacity": 0.9,
    "thickness": 1.2
  },  
  "width":991,
  "height":50,

  "params": [{
    "name": "brush",
    "select": {"type": "interval"}
  }],

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}
  ],

  "encoding": {
    "x":{
      "field": "ShareWomen",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Share of Women",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5, "format": ".0%"},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,1]}
    },
    "color": {
      "condition":{ 
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
          }
        },
      "value": "#d3d3d3" 
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "ShareWomen", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Share of Women"}     
    ] 
  }
  },

  {
  "mark": {
    "type": "tick",
    "opacity": 0.9,
    "thickness": 1.2
  },  
  "width":991,
  "height":50,

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}},
    {"calculate": "1 - datum.ShareWomen", "as": "ShareMen"}
  ],

  "encoding": {
    "x":{
      "field": "ShareMen",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Share of Men",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5, "format": ".0%"},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,1]}
    },
    "color": {
      "condition":{ 
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
          }
      },
      "value": "#d3d3d3" 
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "ShareMen", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Share of Men"}     
    ] 
  }
  }
  
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

You could use the fill property instead  of colour.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2018/2018-10-16/recent-grads.csv"
  },

  "title": "2018 Graduation Explorer",
  "config": {
    "title": {
      "fontSize": 20, 
      "fontWeight": "bold", 
      "offset": 15, 
      "anchor": "middle"
    },
    "axis": {
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": "bold",
      "labelFontSize": 10
    },
    "view": {
      "stroke": "#e8e8e8"
    }
  },

  "spacing": 8,
  "bounds": "full",
  "vconcat": [{
  "hconcat": [

  {  
  "height": 450,
  "width": 500,
  "mark": "circle",
  
  "params": [{
    "name": "Legend_Select",
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Major_category"]},
    "bind": "legend"
  },
  {"name": "brush", "select": {"type": "interval"}}
  ],

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}
  ],
  
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Median",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.2},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,120000]},
      "title": "Median Salary ($)" 
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Unemployment_rate",
      "type": "quantitative",  
      "axis": {"format": ".0%", "gridOpacity": 0.2},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,0.18]},
      "title": "Unemployment Rate (%)"
    },  
    "fill": {   
      "condition":{
        "legend": {
          "orient": "left",
          "symbolSize": 60, 
          "titleFontSize": 10, 
          "labelFontSize": 8, 
          "title": "Major Category",
          "titleAnchor": "middle"
        },  
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
        }
      },
      "value": "lightgrey"      
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major_category", "type": "nominal", "title": "Major Category"},
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Median", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Salary"},
      {"field": "Unemployment_rate", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Unemployment Rate"}  
    ]
  }
  },
  
  {
    
  "width": 300,
  "height": 450,
  "mark": "bar",
  
  "params": [{
    "name": "Gender_Select",
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Gender"]},
    "bind": "legend"
  }],

  
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Men", "Women"], "as": ["Gender", "Total"]},
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}, 
    {"filter": {"param": "brush"}},
    {"filter": {"param": "Gender_Select"}} 
    
  ],  
  
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Major_category", 
      "type": "nominal", 
      "title": null,
      "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "Total", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Total", 
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5},
      "title": "Total No. of Graduates"
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": {
        "symbolSize": 60, 
        "titleFontSize": 10, 
        "labelFontSize": 8, 
        "title": "Gender",
        "titleAnchor": "middle"
      },  
      "field": "Gender", 
      "type": "nominal", 
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["Men", "Women"],
        "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e"]
      }
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major"},
      {"field": "Men", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Men"},
      {"field": "Women", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Women"}
    ]
  }        
  }
  
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}
  },
  
  {
  "mark": {
    "type": "tick",
    "opacity": 0.9,
    "thickness": 1.2
  },  
  "width":991,
  "height":50,

  "params": [{
    "name": "brush",
    "select": {"type": "interval"}
  }],

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}}
  ],

  "encoding": {
    "x":{
      "field": "ShareWomen",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Share of Women",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5, "format": ".0%"},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,1]}
    },
    "color": {
      "condition":{ 
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
          }
        },
      "value": "#d3d3d3" 
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "ShareWomen", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Share of Women"}     
    ] 
  }
  },

  {
  "mark": {
    "type": "tick",
    "opacity": 0.9,
    "thickness": 1.2
  },  
  "width":991,
  "height":50,

  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"param": "Legend_Select"}},
    {"calculate": "1 - datum.ShareWomen", "as": "ShareMen"}
  ],

  "encoding": {
    "x":{
      "field": "ShareMen",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Share of Men",
      "axis": {"gridOpacity": 0.5, "format": ".0%"},
      "scale": {"domain":[0,1]}
    },
    "fill": {
      "condition":{ 
        "param": "brush",
        "field": "Major_category",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain": ["Engineering", "Physical Sciences", "Computers & Mathematics", "Agriculture & Natural Resources", "Industrial Arts & Consumer Services", "Health", "Business", "Communications & Journalism", "Law & Public Policy", "Arts", "Social Science", "Biology & Life Science", "Education", "Humanities & Liberal Arts", "Psychology & Social Work", "Interdisciplinary"], 
          "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf", "#ff9896", "#9edae5", "#aec7e8", "#f7b6d2", "#ffbb78", "#98df8a"]
          }
      },
      "value": "#d3d3d3" 
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Major", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "ShareMen", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2%", "title": "Share of Men"}     
    ] 
  }
  }
  
  ]
}
```